# php echo from a start point to a end point

Tags: php, html, echo

I have built a php site that takes code from a page using GET, and then echos it to the current page, but it exports text like this,

```html
{ "selection13": [ { "name": "L" }, { "name": "100%\nA" } ], "selection7": [ { "name": "S" }, { "name": "100%\nA" } ], "selection8": [ { "name": "SS" }, { "name": "100%\nA" } ], "selection9": [ { "name": "SP" }, { "name": "100%\nA" } ], "selection10": [ { "name": "P" }, { "name": "100%\nA" } ], "selection11": [ { "name": "A" }, { "name": "100.00%\nA+" } ], "selection12": [ { "name": "H", "selection5": [ { "name": "T }, { "name": "100.00%\nA+" } ] }, { "name": "100.00%\nA+", "selection5": [ { "name": "T" }, { "name": "100.00%\nA+" } ] } ] }
```

I need to organizes it in to categorizes like, {L},{100%), here is the code I am currently using,

```html
<?php
$params = http_build_query(array(
  "api_key" => "()",
  "format" => "json"
));

$result = file_get_contents(
    '(url)'.$params,
    false,
    stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET'
        )
    ))
);
echo gzdecode($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is outputting JSON but there appears to be a few issues with the data itself that need to be addressed first.

1. The next to the last `"name": "T`  is missing a closing quote.
2. Section 12 has an inconsistent organization compared to the other sections. Can a section be a child of another section or is this an error?

```json
  "selection11": [
    {
      "name": "A"
    },
    {
      "name": "100.00%\nA+"
    }
  ],
  "selection12": [
    {
      "name": "H",
      "selection5": [
        {
          "name": "T"
        },
        {
          "name": "100.00%\nA+"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "100.00%\nA+",
      "selection5": [
        {
          "name": "T"
        },
        {
          "name": "100.00%\nA+"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

These 2 issues need to be fixed in the JSON data you are retrieving first.

From there, the best way to reorganize this is to convert it to an array using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$json = gzdecode($result);
$resultArray = json_decode($json);
```

I can't tell from your question exactly how you want to reorganize the data but use one or more of the builtin [array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to get the data in the structure you want. If you need to output it in JSON, use json_encode on the manipulated array to get the final data format. More specific help can be provided if you can be more clear on want output structure you are looking for and the format (does it need to be JSON or something else).